# jQuery check information on different page to influence current page

Tags: jquery

Hi with jQuery Can you look at a different page and if an element or attribute exists on that page, it makes a change on the current page?

I have a listing page with a bunch of products (.productListItem) containing links through to pages that have information about the product including stock levels.

I'm trying to check the stock levels on the product page (different page) for each product on the listing page (current page) and if there is no stock then hide that product from the listing page (current page).

I've wrote this script to follow the current products href and simply log what information it could return:

```js
$('.productListItem .itemContainer>a').each(function(){

    var storePLU = $(this).attr('href');
    var stockURL = storePLU + 'stock/';

    $.get( stockURL, function( data ) {
      console.log( data );
    });

  });
```

and it returns some information in to the console like this which looks like could be used:

```html
<div id="itemOptions" data-stock="false">
  <div id="sizeOptions" class="sizeOptions ">
    <h3>
          Out Of Stock
    </h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

I believe I should be able to use this information (but I've not figured out how) for example, use the information logged in the console so:

`if data-stock="false" ( .productListItem, this ).hide();`

or

`if #itemOptions #sizeOptions h3:contains("Out Of Stock") ( .productListItem, this ).hide();`

Comment: While it's possible to do this, through AJAX, it would make far more sense to use the same server-side logic as exists on the product page on this page. Then you can show the stock level in the page as it renders, without having to waste an entire page request just to get the stock count.

Comment: If `data` is a string of HTML then you should be able to wrap it in a jQuery function: `$(data)` and query it like any other jQuery object.  Though I certainly agree with the above comment that there are better ways to accomplish this if you have control over the whole system.  But if you're scraping server-side data that you can't otherwise access, your options may be limited.

Comment: Thanks for the advice but you would be surprised how little access you have working with a system supplied & controlled by external sources and you have to use another external app to build & setup injected tests, just so you can get evidence that its worth the costs to implement correctly by said external sources. Everything is kind of limiting & against us here so think out of the box whether it's not the most optimised way is the only option we have. So any help to use that information I've pulled back with JQuery in an if statement would really be appreciated? or is it not possible?